# Navigation Bar IE8 issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, uinavigationbar, zurb-foundation

I'm building a html website using foundation.zurb 4 framework and now I'm having an issue on making the nav bar work on IE8. I kind of manage to make everything work on IE8 except that nav bar. I'm using a separate css file for the nav bar menu and another one for the IE8 tweaks. All the files can be found [here](http://creativusmouse.com/files/html.zip).

I'd like to apologise the fact that the code is quite long and hope my request is not a bit too much to ask. I hope someone could help me as I'm getting a bit desperate now :(

**Update**: See it in action [here](http://creativusmouse.com/files/html/index.html) It doesn't need to be responsive on IE8 I just want it to be static ;)

Comment: Instead of an attachment can you add this to jsfiddle? It's more convenient that way

Comment: I tried to do it and it got a bit weird. http://jsfiddle.net/CajyT/
This is a responsive nav bar so you'll have to stretch the window a little to see the whole thing.
Best regards

Comment: there's a lot of things that ie8 does not support that you have (html5 and css3)....do you have something like Modernizr to support old browsers?

Comment: It has modernizr too but it just doesn't work. The nav bar disappears completely on IE8

Answer (score 1):

Media Queries - Responsive CSS3 is not supported for ie8 or less.

You are using this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 58.75em)
.top-bar .toggle-topbar {
display: none;
}
```

IE8 is like..."WTFISTHIS?"

Meaning it tries doing it but it just doesn't understand going back and forth

There is this plugin:

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

If you really need to support it but my answer is to let ie8 be static like a regular desktop version.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say that I don't need it to be responsive on IE8 I just need to make it static and look pretty much like in modern browsers.

Comment: Great! Please make sure you approve this answer :)

Comment: I just tried using Respond plugin and it didn't work. When I load the page the menu is still missing

Comment: yeah stick to ie8 static, plugins are not the way to rely

Comment: from the looks of it your nav is being done with jquery...thats breaking in ie8

Comment: I still keep having the same problem. Probably is the jquery or maybe something else. I just can't figure it out :'(

Comment: Can't you just make the menu with CSS? with transition so you can get the same effect? That way jquery is not building it and you will have more control